# Why can't I find anything on the non-deterministic Nick's Class (NNC)?

Tags: complexity-theory

It seems that non-deterministic Nick's Class (NNC) would be the same as non-deterministic polynomial time, but I haven't been able to find anything on NNC.

Comment: Maybe [this blog article](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2009/06/nondeterministic-parallelism.html) is helpful.